# How to enhance JQuery Code to make it easy to upload my files through Upload button and then delete these files smoothly

Tags: jquery

Actually i upload multiple files to appear in html lines(section contains the lines of the uploaded files) without any problem, but when i try to delete them all from html one by one ,i can not delete the last file,
also when i try to upload the same files again the upload file button does not permit unless i choose other files, i observed that the selected files appear registered in button(when mouse over the button) although i deleted some of them

i tried to work on jquery enhancement but all in vain

```
var selectedFilesNames = [];


// Add events
$('input[type=file]').on('change', prepareUpload);
var fileData = new FormData();
var files;
// Grab the files and set them to our variable
function prepareUpload(event) {
    files = event.target.files;

    $.each(files, function (key, value) {
    var isExistFile = false;
    for (var pair of fileData.entries()) {
            if (pair[1].name === value.name) {
                isExistFile = true;
                alert("file: " + value.name + " Is already Exist");
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (!isExistFile) {
            var row = $("<tr data-fileNametr='" + value.name + "'></tr>");
            var col1 = $("<td>" + value.name + "</td>");
            //var col3 = $("<td><a href='#'><i data-fileName='" + value.name + "' class='btnRemove'></i></a></td>");
            var col2 = $("<td><a href='javascript:void(0)'><i data-fileName='" + value.name + "' class='fa fa-times red btnRemove'></i></a></td>");
            var col3 = $("<td></td>");
            row.append(col1, col2, col3).prependTo("#tblFiles");
            fileData.append(key, value);

        }
        return true;
    });

    $(".btnRemove").on("click", function () {
        var fileName = $(this).attr("data-fileName"); 
        for (var pair of fileData.entries()) {
            if (pair[1].name === fileName) {
                fileData.delete(pair[0]);
                return false;
            }
            $(this).parent().parent().parent().remove();
        }


        return true;
    });

}
```

Comment: actually i will be appreciated for any help

Comment: note in jquery i checked for not selecting any file more than one time like that
    for (var pair of fileData.entries()) {
                if (pair[1].name === value.name) {
                    isExistFile = true;
                    alert("file: " + value.name + " Is already Exist");
                    return false;
                }
            }

Comment: your help is very urgent for me, truth

Comment: your help is appreciated, thanks